# Error [freeglut: failed to open display ''] in macOS OpenGL

Tags: macos, opengl, makefile, freeglut

I am trying to implement an open-source OpenGL implementation of a 3D Rubik's Cube. The compilation of the code works in my non-mac machines, but when run in max, it runs into:

```
freeglut (./OpenGL): failed to open display ''
```

Libraries I used: GLUT (freeglut), GLFW, GLM

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct cube_rotate
{

  GLfloat angle, x, y, z;
};

GLfloat angle, fAspect, cube_size;
GLint rot_x, rot_y, crement, x_0, x_k, y_0, y_k, z_0, z_k, gap, gap_crement;
// cube_rotate cube_rotations[3][3][3];
vector<cube_rotate> cube_rotations[3][3][3];

void load_visualization_parameters(void);

void apply_rotation(GLfloat angle)
{

  vector<cube_rotate> face[3][3];
  int index;
  cube_rotate rotation;

  // copy face to be rotated
  // apply rotation to face
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {

      index = 2 - j % 3;

      if (x_0 == x_k)
      {
        rotation = {angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
        face[index][i] = cube_rotations[x_k][i][j];
      }

      if (y_0 == y_k)
      {
        rotation = {angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0};
        face[index][i] = cube_rotations[j][y_k][i];
      }

      if (z_0 == z_k)
      {
        rotation = {-1 * angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
        face[index][i] = cube_rotations[j][i][z_k];
      }

      face[index][i].push_back(rotation);
    }

  // copy back rotated face
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {

      if (x_0 == x_k)
        cube_rotations[x_k][i][j] = face[i][j];

      if (y_0 == y_k)
        cube_rotations[j][y_k][i] = face[i][j];

      if (z_0 == z_k)
        cube_rotations[j][i][z_k] = face[i][j];
    }
}

// reset face selection parameters
void reset_selected_face()
{

  x_0 = 0;
  x_k = 2;
  y_0 = 0;
  y_k = 2;
  z_0 = 0;
  z_k = 2;
}

void set_camera()
{

  gluLookAt(0, 80, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
}

// draw a cube
void draw_cube(int x, int y, int z)
{

  vector<cube_rotate> lrot = cube_rotations[x][y][z];

  glPushMatrix();

  // translate to final position
  glTranslatef((x - 1) * cube_size + x * gap, (y - 1) * cube_size + y * gap, (z - 1) * cube_size + z * gap);

  // rotate cube to correct position
  for (int i = lrot.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    glRotatef(lrot[i].angle, lrot[i].x, lrot[i].y, lrot[i].z);

  glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);         // front
  glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // face normal
  glVertex3f(cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(-cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(-cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2);
  glEnd();

  glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);          // back
  glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0); // face normal
  glVertex3f(cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(-cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(-cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2);
  glEnd();

  glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);          // left
  glNormal3f(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // face normal
  glVertex3f(-cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(-cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(-cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(-cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2);
  glEnd();

  glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);         // right
  glNormal3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // face normal
  glVertex3f(cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2);
  glEnd();

  glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);         // top
  glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // face normal
  glVertex3f(-cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(-cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2);
  glEnd();

  glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);          // bottom
  glNormal3f(0.0, -1.0, 0.0); // face normal
  glVertex3f(-cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2);
  glVertex3f(-cube_size / 2, -cube_size / 2, cube_size / 2);
  glEnd();

  glPopMatrix();

} // draw cube function

// draw function
void draw_func(void)
{

  int x = -cube_size, y = -cube_size, z = -cube_size;

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  // reset transformations
  glLoadIdentity();

  // set camera position
  set_camera();

  // apply visualization transformations
  glRotatef(rot_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // rotate in y axis
  glRotatef(rot_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // rotate in x axis

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)   // step through x axis
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) // step through y axis
      for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
      { // step through z axis

        // draw a single cube
        draw_cube(i, j, k);
      }

  // flush opengl commands
  glutSwapBuffers();
}

// init rendering parameters
void init_func(void)
{

  // init parameters
  cube_size = 30.0; // cuboid size
  rot_x = 0.0;      // view rotation x
  rot_y = 0.0;      // view rotation y
  crement = 5;      // rotation (in/de)crement
  gap = 5;
  gap_crement = 3;
  // initialize cuboid rotations

  // init lighting
  GLfloat ambient_lighte[4] = {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0};
  GLfloat diffuse_light[4] = {0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0};  // color
  GLfloat specular_light[4] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}; // brightness
  GLfloat light_position[4] = {0.0, 50.0, 50.0, 1.0};

  // material brightness capacity
  GLfloat specularity[4] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
  GLint material_specularity = 60;

  // black background
  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

  // Gouraud colorization model
  glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

  // material reflectability
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, specularity);
  // brightness concentration
  glMateriali(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, material_specularity);

  // activate ambient light
  glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambient_lighte);

  // define light parameters
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient_lighte);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse_light);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specular_light);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

  // enable changing material color
  glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
  // enable lighting
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
  // enable depth buffering
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  angle = 45;

} // init

// specify what's shown in the window
void load_visualization_parameters(void)
{
  // specify projection coordinate system
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();

  // specify projection perspective
  gluPerspective(angle, fAspect, 0.4, 500);

  // init model coordinate system
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();

  // specify observer and target positions
  set_camera();
} // load visualization parameters

// window reshape callback
void reshape_func(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
  // prevents division by zero
  if (h == 0)
    h = 1;

  // viewport size
  glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

  // aspect ratio
  fAspect = (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h;

  load_visualization_parameters();
} // reshape function

// keyboard function callback
void keyboard_func(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{

  switch (key)
  {

  case '+':
    gap += gap_crement;
    break;

  case '-':
    gap -= gap_crement;
    break;
  // view rotation
  // INcrement or DEcrement
  case 'L': // right
  case 'l':
    rot_y = (rot_y - crement) % 360;
    break;

  case 'J': // left
  case 'j':
    rot_y = (rot_y + crement) % 360;
    break;

  case 'I': // down
  case 'i':
    rot_x = (rot_x + crement) % 360;
    break;

  case 'K': // up
  case 'k':
    rot_x = (rot_x - crement) % 360;
    break;
  // end of view rotation

  // cube movements

  // select cube face
  // x-axis faces
  case 'Q':
  case 'q':
    reset_selected_face();
    x_0 = 0;
    x_k = 0;
    break;

  case 'W':
  case 'w':
    reset_selected_face();
    x_0 = 1;
    x_k = 1;
    break;

  case 'E':
  case 'e':
    reset_selected_face();
    x_0 = 2;
    x_k = 2;
    break;

  // y-axis faces
  case 'A':
  case 'a':
    reset_selected_face();
    y_0 = 0;
    y_k = 0;
    break;

  case 'S':
  case 's':
    reset_selected_face();
    y_0 = 1;
    y_k = 1;
    break;

  case 'D':
  case 'd':
    reset_selected_face();
    y_0 = 2;
    y_k = 2;
    break;

  // z-axis faces
  case 'C':
  case 'c':
    reset_selected_face();
    z_0 = 0;
    z_k = 0;
    break;

  case 'X':
  case 'x':
    reset_selected_face();
    z_0 = 1;
    z_k = 1;
    break;

  case 'Z':
  case 'z':
    reset_selected_face();
    z_0 = 2;
    z_k = 2;
    break;

  // move selected face
  case 'U': // counter-clockwise
  case 'u':
    apply_rotation(-90);
    break;

  case 'O': // clockwise
  case 'o':
    apply_rotation(90);
    break;

    // end of cube movements

  default:
    break;
  }

  glutPostRedisplay();
}

// mouse function callback
void mouse_func(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
  if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
    { // Zoom-in
      if (angle >= 10)
        angle -= 5;
    }
  if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON)
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
    { // Zoom-out
      if (angle <= 130)
        angle += 5;
    }
  load_visualization_parameters();
  glutPostRedisplay();
} // mouse function

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(400, 350);
  glutCreateWindow("Rubik's Cube!");
  glutDisplayFunc(draw_func);
  glutReshapeFunc(reshape_func);
  glutMouseFunc(mouse_func);
  glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard_func);
  init_func();
  glutMainLoop();
} // main
```

The Makefile for this code:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
LDFLAGS = -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glfw/3.3.8/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/freeglut/3.4.0/lib -framework OpenGL -lglfw -lglut

INCLUDE_DIRS = -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glfw/3.3.8/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glm/0.9.9.8/include -I/Users/*****/Library/CloudStorage/****\ ***/include

SRC = main.cpp
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE = OpenGL

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

I have been able to successfully output the program in Fedora Builds, but for my macOS system, after changing the libraries into proper ones, and avoiding depreciation warnings, I just can't seem to compile this code. I'm very new to OpenGL and this has been my first couple of weeks of working my way through setting up the libraries. Any help/suggestions are highly appreciated. I am putting the C++ code and makefile I used for the compilation.

Comment: Why do you tag the question with [tag:glfw]? You are using GLUT, but not GLFW.

Comment: Also, the tag [tag:glm-math] is not important for this question, but [tag:makefile] is.

Comment: I updated the tags for this question

Comment: To the best of my knowledge OpenGL and its extension libraries such as freeglut depend on X11, even on MacOS.  XQuartz is the usual X11 implementation for MacOS.  Do you have XQuartz or another X11 implementation installed?  If so, can you launch it successfully?